# GL_SAMPLE_ALPHA_TO_COVERAGE in MSAA

Tags: opengl

Does it make sense to use [GL_SAMPLE_ALPHA_TO_COVERAGE_ARB](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Transparency_Sorting#GL_SAMPLE_ALPHA_TO_COVERAGE) when rendering into MSAA FBO? Or it is rather an alternative to multisampling when alpha blending is processed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alpha to coverage is actually only useful (and thus only used at all) *with* multisampling, since it transforms a fragment's alpha value into an appropriate coverage value used for determining the contribution of the fragment to its respective samples. Without multisampling this doesn't make any sense at all. [Alpha to coverage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_to_coverage) on its own doesn't do any antialiasing. It is used to improve the multisampling behaviour of highly alpha-tested things (like wire fence or alpha-tested tree leaves and grass), which otherwise don't really profit from multisampling (since it only really works on polygon-edges while those things just consist of a single large polygon) leaving quite jaggy boundaries.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that out.However I wonder, is it enabled by default?Because without explicitly setting it I am still getting smooth edges for alpha blended stuff with MSAA.

Comment: @MichaelIV It shouldn't be enabled by default. Maybe you are just experiencing the usual multisapling working on polygon edges (keep in mind that alpha-to-coverage really only pays for non-geometric "gaps" inside the actual geometry, so the usual alph-testing scenarios, simple "overall transparent" alpha-blended geometry will work perfectly with MSAA already). Or maybe in your scene the usual problems aren't that noticable.

Comment: The second is more likely as I am referring to the case where the edges are defined by transparent alpha and not by geometry bounds.

Comment: @ChristianRau I am confused by your answer, do you mean that enabling Alpha-To-Coverage without using Multi-Sampling has no effect on the rendering? [This presentation by NVidia's Sarah Tariq](http://sarahtariq.com/Chapter3-HairCourseNotes_AntialiasingAndTransparency.pdf#page=21) says that `Alpha-to-coverage will work regardless of whether or not multisampling is also turned on`. Do you mean using Alpha-to-coverage without MSAA is only useful for rendering foliage or similar stuff?

Comment: @wil I'm not sure how this sentence in that presentation is meant, but yeah, alpha-to-coverage only works with MSAA. Or said otherwise, when MSAA is disabled there is just absolutely no use for the generated coverage mask. Alpha-to-coverage *with* MSAA is useful for rendering foliage and similar stuff. And alpha-to-coverage *without* MSAA is useful for *nothing*. This also follows from the presentation you linked to, wasn't it for that slightly confusing sentence in there. Maybe they meant it's still working, albeit useless, but that wouldn't make too much sense either.

Comment: Actually, alpha to coverage makes perfect sense in a non-MSAA context.  The purpose is to compute the number of fragments covered, with rounding, given an alpha value i.e. coverageCount = round(alpha * numFragmentsPerPixel).  When numFragmentsPerPixel is 1, this yields either 0 or 1 depending on whether alpha is less than or greater than 0.5 - i.e. it does standard non-MSAA alpha testing.